# Error message not captured despite stdout and stderr redirection

Tags: python, stdout, ubuntu-16.04, stderr

I was running a piece of python code on a server overnight (`Ubuntu 16.04`). In order to not be dependent on the connection I ran the script inside `screen`. I however wanted to be able to capture all screen output to review it the next morning so as suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/485762/564528) ,I redirected `stdout` and `stderr` to a file as follows:

```
python -u edge_prediction_stats.py 2>&1 | tee ./screengrab.dat
```

When logging back in this morning the script had crashed with error messages that however not been captured (though all regular output prior to the error messages seem to have been captured). Having run the script in `screen` I can't scroll back terribly far.

Why has this behaviour not been captured and how would I be able to capture it? Also, does anybody know what these error messages mean?

**EDIT:**
Following suggestions in the comments that the problem is caused by `tee` I reran the code without consolte redirection and without `screen`. It persits. The complete error output is the following (to keep within the maximum post length the old error output was deleted and some of the Memory Map section here was cropped):

```
*** Error in `python': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000033db2c0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7ff250de37e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7fe0a)[0x7ff250debe0a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7ff250def98c]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/libgraph_tool_core.so(+0x1bf83b1)[0x7ff2405333b1]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0(+0x2547c)[0x7ff23e4eb47c]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xae435)[0x7ff251b10435]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x8ecab)[0x7ff251af0cab]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xae4f1)[0x7ff251b104f1]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x8ecab)[0x7ff251af0cab]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xae4f1)[0x7ff251b104f1]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x7f08f)[0x7ff251ae108f]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x8ecab)[0x7ff251af0cab]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0xae4f1)[0x7ff251b104f1]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x8cbe7)[0x7ff251aeebe7]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyDict_SetItem+0x8c)[0x7ff251af203c]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x6ae0)[0x7ff251b5d010]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x89e)[0x7ff251b5fa2e]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCode+0x32)[0x7ff251b5fb42]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyRun_FileExFlags+0xb0)[0x7ff251b80050]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags+0xef)[0x7ff251b8022f]
/home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(Py_Main+0xca4)[0x7ff251b95b74]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7ff250d8c830]
python[0x400649]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 87037196                           /home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/python2.7
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 08:11 87037196                           /home/pmj27/anaconda/bin/python2.7
00f8f000-3110f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ff174000000-7ff174021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff174021000-7ff178000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff17bbe7000-7ff184000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff184000000-7ff184021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff184021000-7ff188000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff188000000-7ff188021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff188021000-7ff18c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
.
.
.
7ff224f2a000-7ff22532a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22532a000-7ff22532b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22532b000-7ff22672c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22672c000-7ff226817000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 115217209                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/util/libgraph_tool_util.so
7ff226817000-7ff226a16000 ---p 000eb000 08:11 115217209                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/util/libgraph_tool_util.so
7ff226a16000-7ff226a1a000 r--p 000ea000 08:11 115217209                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/util/libgraph_tool_util.so
7ff226a1a000-7ff226a1b000 rw-p 000ee000 08:11 115217209                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/util/libgraph_tool_util.so
7ff226a1b000-7ff2276bc000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 114962515                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/search/libgraph_tool_search.so
7ff2276bc000-7ff2278bb000 ---p 00ca1000 08:11 114962515                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/search/libgraph_tool_search.so
7ff2278bb000-7ff2278cc000 r--p 00ca0000 08:11 114962515                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/search/libgraph_tool_search.so
7ff2278cc000-7ff2278d3000 rw-p 00cb1000 08:11 114962515                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/search/libgraph_tool_search.so
7ff2278d3000-7ff227971000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 87690910                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/clustering/libgraph_tool_clustering.so
7ff227971000-7ff227b70000 ---p 0009e000 08:11 87690910                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/clustering/libgraph_tool_clustering.so
7ff227b70000-7ff227b73000 r--p 0009d000 08:11 87690910                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/clustering/libgraph_tool_clustering.so
7ff227b73000-7ff227b74000 rw-p 000a0000 08:11 87690910                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/clustering/libgraph_tool_clustering.so
7ff227b74000-7ff227b75000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff227b75000-7ff227b7c000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 86908066                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libpathplan.so.4.0.0
7ff227b7c000-7ff227d7c000 ---p 00007000 08:11 86908066                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libpathplan.so.4.0.0
7ff227d7c000-7ff227d7d000 rw-p 00007000 08:11 86908066                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libpathplan.so.4.0.0
7ff227d7d000-7ff227d82000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 86908050                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libcdt.so.5.0.0
7ff227d82000-7ff227f81000 ---p 00005000 08:11 86908050                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libcdt.so.5.0.0
7ff227f81000-7ff227f82000 rw-p 00004000 08:11 86908050                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libcdt.so.5.0.0
7ff227f82000-7ff227f96000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 86908054                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libcgraph.so.6.0.0
7ff227f96000-7ff228195000 ---p 00014000 08:11 86908054                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libcgraph.so.6.0.0
7ff228195000-7ff228197000 rw-p 00013000 08:11 86908054                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libcgraph.so.6.0.0
7ff228197000-7ff22819b000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 86908070                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libxdot.so.4.0.0
7ff22819b000-7ff22839a000 ---p 00004000 08:11 86908070                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libxdot.so.4.0.0
7ff22839a000-7ff22839b000 rw-p 00003000 08:11 86908070                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libxdot.so.4.0.0
7ff22839b000-7ff228428000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 86775922                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libgvc.so.6.0.0
7ff228428000-7ff228628000 ---p 0008d000 08:11 86775922                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libgvc.so.6.0.0
7ff228628000-7ff228639000 rw-p 0008d000 08:11 86775922                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libgvc.so.6.0.0
7ff228639000-7ff22873a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22873a000-7ff22b540000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 88999518                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/inference/libgraph_tool_inference.so
7ff22b540000-7ff22b73f000 ---p 02e06000 08:11 88999518                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/inference/libgraph_tool_inference.so
7ff22b73f000-7ff22b789000 r--p 02e05000 08:11 88999518                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/inference/libgraph_tool_inference.so
7ff22b789000-7ff22b7c9000 rw-p 02e4f000 08:11 88999518                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/inference/libgraph_tool_inference.so
7ff22b7c9000-7ff22b7cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22b7cf000-7ff22bb31000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 115086211                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/spectral/libgraph_tool_spectral.so
7ff22bb31000-7ff22bd31000 ---p 00362000 08:11 115086211                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/spectral/libgraph_tool_spectral.so
7ff22bd31000-7ff22bd33000 r--p 00362000 08:11 115086211                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/spectral/libgraph_tool_spectral.so
7ff22bd33000-7ff22bd34000 rw-p 00364000 08:11 115086211                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/spectral/libgraph_tool_spectral.so
7ff22bd34000-7ff22bd74000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22bd74000-7ff22c1c4000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 88219622                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/libgraph_tool_draw.so
7ff22c1c4000-7ff22c3c3000 ---p 00450000 08:11 88219622                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/libgraph_tool_draw.so
7ff22c3c3000-7ff22c3d4000 r--p 0044f000 08:11 88219622                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/libgraph_tool_draw.so
7ff22c3d4000-7ff22c3d6000 rw-p 00460000 08:11 88219622                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/libgraph_tool_draw.so
7ff22c3d6000-7ff22c457000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22c457000-7ff22c45b000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 111289477                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_lsprof.so
7ff22c45b000-7ff22c65a000 ---p 00004000 08:11 111289477                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_lsprof.so
7ff22c65a000-7ff22c65b000 rw-p 00003000 08:11 111289477                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_lsprof.so
7ff22c65b000-7ff22c75c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22c75c000-7ff22c821000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 87430398                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7ff22c821000-7ff22ca21000 ---p 000c5000 08:11 87430398                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7ff22ca21000-7ff22ca25000 rw-p 000c5000 08:11 87430398                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7ff22ca25000-7ff22cae6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22cb12000-7ff22cbd2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22cbd2000-7ff22cbe3000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 111289482                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
7ff22cbe3000-7ff22cde3000 ---p 00011000 08:11 111289482                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
7ff22cde3000-7ff22cde6000 rw-p 00011000 08:11 111289482                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
7ff22cde6000-7ff22d266000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22d266000-7ff22d268000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 111289509                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/resource.so
7ff22d268000-7ff22d468000 ---p 00002000 08:11 111289509                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/resource.so
7ff22d468000-7ff22d469000 rw-p 00002000 08:11 111289509                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/resource.so
7ff22d469000-7ff22d46d000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 111289514                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/termios.so
7ff22d46d000-7ff22d66d000 ---p 00004000 08:11 111289514                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/termios.so
7ff22d66d000-7ff22d66f000 rw-p 00004000 08:11 111289514                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/termios.so
7ff22d66f000-7ff22d86f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22d86f000-7ff22d8c9000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 90316181                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_qhull.so
7ff22d8c9000-7ff22dac8000 ---p 0005a000 08:11 90316181                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_qhull.so
7ff22dac8000-7ff22daca000 rw-p 00059000 08:11 90316181                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_qhull.so
7ff22daca000-7ff22dacc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22dacc000-7ff22dae8000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 90316182                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_tri.so
7ff22dae8000-7ff22dce7000 ---p 0001c000 08:11 90316182                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_tri.so
7ff22dce7000-7ff22dce8000 rw-p 0001b000 08:11 90316182                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_tri.so
7ff22dce8000-7ff22dce9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22dce9000-7ff22dcf6000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 90316172                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_contour.so
7ff22dcf6000-7ff22def6000 ---p 0000d000 08:11 90316172                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_contour.so
7ff22def6000-7ff22def7000 rw-p 0000d000 08:11 90316172                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_contour.so
7ff22def7000-7ff22defd000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 90316171                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_cntr.so
7ff22defd000-7ff22e0fc000 ---p 00006000 08:11 90316171                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_cntr.so
7ff22e0fc000-7ff22e0fd000 rw-p 00005000 08:11 90316171                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_cntr.so
7ff22e0fd000-7ff22e11f000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 90316174                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_image.so
7ff22e11f000-7ff22e31f000 ---p 00022000 08:11 90316174                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_image.so
7ff22e31f000-7ff22e320000 rw-p 00022000 08:11 90316174                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_image.so
7ff22e320000-7ff22e321000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22e321000-7ff22e327000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 90316178                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so
7ff22e327000-7ff22e526000 ---p 00006000 08:11 90316178                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so
7ff22e526000-7ff22e527000 rw-p 00005000 08:11 90316178                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so
7ff22e527000-7ff22e5bd000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 111289516                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so
7ff22e5bd000-7ff22e7bc000 ---p 00096000 08:11 111289516                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so
7ff22e7bc000-7ff22e7d0000 rw-p 00095000 08:11 111289516                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so
7ff22e7d0000-7ff22ecd0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22ecd0000-7ff22ece3000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 90316376                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so
7ff22ece3000-7ff22eee2000 ---p 00013000 08:11 90316376                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so
7ff22eee2000-7ff22eee4000 rw-p 00012000 08:11 90316376                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so
7ff22eee4000-7ff22f024000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22f024000-7ff22f053000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 90316177                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so
7ff22f053000-7ff22f252000 ---p 0002f000 08:11 90316177                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so
7ff22f252000-7ff22f254000 rw-p 0002e000 08:11 90316177                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so
7ff22f254000-7ff22f25c000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 111289475                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_json.so
7ff22f25c000-7ff22f45c000 ---p 00008000 08:11 111289475                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_json.so
7ff22f45c000-7ff22f45d000 rw-p 00008000 08:11 111289475                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_json.so
7ff22f45d000-7ff22f45f000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 111289456                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.so
7ff22f45f000-7ff22f65e000 ---p 00002000 08:11 111289456                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.so
7ff22f65e000-7ff22f65f000 rw-p 00001000 08:11 111289456                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.so
7ff22f65f000-7ff22f9a0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22f9a0000-7ff22f9b4000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 111289483                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
7ff22f9b4000-7ff22fbb3000 ---p 00014000 08:11 111289483                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
7ff22fbb3000-7ff22fbb7000 rw-p 00013000 08:11 111289483                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
7ff22fbb7000-7ff22fbc5000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 111289481                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
7ff22fbc5000-7ff22fdc5000 ---p 0000e000 08:11 111289481                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
7ff22fdc5000-7ff22fdca000 rw-p 0000e000 08:11 111289481                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
7ff22fdca000-7ff22feca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff22feca000-7ff22fece000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 111289510                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so
7ff22fece000-7ff2300ce000 ---p 00004000 08:11 111289510                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so
7ff2300ce000-7ff2300d0000 rw-p 00004000 08:11 111289510                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so
7ff2300d0000-7ff230190000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff230190000-7ff230192000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5898446                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7ff230192000-7ff230392000 ---p 00002000 08:01 5898446                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7ff230392000-7ff230393000 r--p 00002000 08:01 5898446                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7ff230393000-7ff230394000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 5898446                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
7ff230394000-7ff2303b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 87821207                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7ff2303b8000-7ff2305b7000 ---p 00024000 08:11 87821207                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7ff2305b7000-7ff2305b8000 rw-p 00023000 08:11 87821207                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0
7ff2305b8000-7ff2306a6000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 86776648                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libiconv.so.2.5.1
7ff2306a6000-7ff2308a5000 ---p 000ee000 08:11 86776648                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libiconv.so.2.5.1
7ff2308a5000-7ff2308a7000 rw-p 000ed000 08:11 86776648                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libiconv.so.2.5.1
7ff2308a7000-7ff2309f7000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 87949924                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.2
7ff2309f7000-7ff230bf6000 ---p 00150000 08:11 87949924                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.2
7ff230bf6000-7ff230c00000 rw-p 0014f000 08:11 87949924                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libxml2.so.2.9.2
7ff230c00000-7ff230c01000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff230c01000-7ff230c12000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5907443                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7ff230c12000-7ff230e11000 ---p 00011000 08:01 5907443                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7ff230e11000-7ff230e12000 r--p 00010000 08:01 5907443                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7ff230e12000-7ff230e13000 rw-p 00011000 08:01 5907443                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
7ff230e13000-7ff230f48000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5907424                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7ff230f48000-7ff231148000 ---p 00135000 08:01 5907424                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7ff231148000-7ff231149000 r--p 00135000 08:01 5907424                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7ff231149000-7ff23114d000 rw-p 00136000 08:01 5907424                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
7ff23114d000-7ff231156000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 5901237                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7ff231156000-7ff231355000 ---p 00009000 08:01 5901237                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7ff231355000-7ff231356000 r--p 00008000 08:01 5901237                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7ff231356000-7ff231357000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 5901237                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
7ff231357000-7ff231397000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 87561104                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libpng16.so.16.28.0
7ff231397000-7ff231596000 ---p 00040000 08:11 87561104                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libpng16.so.16.28.0
7ff231596000-7ff231597000 rw-p 0003f000 08:11 87561104                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libpng16.so.16.28.0
7ff231597000-7ff23162b000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 87561082                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libfreetype.so.6.11.4
7ff23162b000-7ff23182a000 ---p 00094000 08:11 87561082                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libfreetype.so.6.11.4
7ff23182a000-7ff231830000 rw-p 00093000 08:11 87561082                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libfreetype.so.6.11.4
7ff231830000-7ff23186d000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 86776705                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libfontconfig.so.1.9.2
7ff23186d000-7ff231a6d000 ---p 0003d000 08:11 86776705                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libfontconfig.so.1.9.2
7ff231a6d000-7ff231a73000 rw-p 0003d000 08:11 86776705                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libfontconfig.so.1.9.2
7ff231a73000-7ff231b17000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 102500080                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libpixman-1.so.0.34.0
7ff231b17000-7ff231d17000 ---p 000a4000 08:11 102500080                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libpixman-1.so.0.34.0
7ff231d17000-7ff231d1f000 rw-p 000a4000 08:11 102500080                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libpixman-1.so.0.34.0
7ff231d1f000-7ff231e60000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 102500362                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libcairo.so.2.11400.8
7ff231e60000-7ff23205f000 ---p 00141000 08:11 102500362                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libcairo.so.2.11400.8
7ff23205f000-7ff232063000 rw-p 00140000 08:11 102500362                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libcairo.so.2.11400.8
7ff232063000-7ff232064000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff232064000-7ff232078000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 115085801                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.so
7ff232078000-7ff232278000 ---p 00014000 08:11 115085801                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.so
7ff232278000-7ff23227d000 rw-p 00014000 08:11 115085801                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.so
7ff23227d000-7ff2329da000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 88219624                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/libgraph_tool_layout.so
7ff2329da000-7ff232bd9000 ---p 0075d000 08:11 88219624                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/libgraph_tool_layout.so
7ff232bd9000-7ff232bdd000 r--p 0075c000 08:11 88219624                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/libgraph_tool_layout.so
7ff232bdd000-7ff232be1000 rw-p 00760000 08:11 88219624                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/libgraph_tool_layout.so
7ff232be1000-7ff232c7b000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 91488846                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libgmp.so.10.2.0
7ff232c7b000-7ff232e7a000 ---p 0009a000 08:11 91488846                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libgmp.so.10.2.0
7ff232e7a000-7ff232e7c000 rw-p 00099000 08:11 91488846                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/libgmp.so.10.2.0
7ff232e7c000-7ff234059000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 88740332                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/generation/libgraph_tool_generation.so
7ff234059000-7ff234259000 ---p 011dd000 08:11 88740332                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/generation/libgraph_tool_generation.so
7ff234259000-7ff23425e000 r--p 011dd000 08:11 88740332                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/generation/libgraph_tool_generation.so
7ff23425e000-7ff234264000 rw-p 011e2000 08:11 88740332                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/generation/libgraph_tool_generation.so
7ff234264000-7ff2342a5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ff2342a5000-7ff2349b9000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 88477126                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/flow/libgraph_tool_flow.so
7ff2349b9000-7ff234bb9000 ---p 00714000 08:11 88477126                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/flow/libgraph_tool_flow.so
7ff234bb9000-7ff234bbb000 r--p 00714000 08:11 88477126                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/flow/libgraph_tool_flow.so
7ff234bbb000-7ff234bbe000 rw-p 00716000 08:11 88477126                   /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/flow/libgraph_tool_flow.so
7ff234bbe000-7ff234d7b000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 115086279                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/stats/libgraph_tool_stats.so
7ff234d7b000-7ff234f7a000 ---p 001bd000 08:11 115086279                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/stats/libgraph_tool_stats.so
7ff234f7a000-7ff234f7d000 r--p 001bc000 08:11 115086279                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/stats/libgraph_tool_stats.so
7ff234f7d000-7ff234f7f000 rw-p 001bf000 08:11 115086279                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/stats/libgraph_tool_stats.so
7ff234f7f000-7ff2388d3000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 115086288                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/topology/libgraph_tool_topology.so
7ff2388d3000-7ff238ad2000 ---p 03954000 08:11 115086288                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/topology/libgraph_tool_topology.so
7ff238ad2000-7ff238ada000 r--p 03953000 08:11 115086288                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/topology/libgraph_tool_topology.so
7ff238ada000-7ff238b05000 rw-p 0395b000 08:11 115086288                  /home/pmj27/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/topology/libgraph_tool_topology.so
7ff238b05000-7ff238b06000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Note: those messages look like the contents of `/proc/<PID>/maps`, not Python output (although the references to Python libraries are suspicious). Are you sure that the program actually crashed? Is there any chance you could post the code you were trying to run?

Comment: Those are not error messages from your process with redirected `stdout` and `stderr`. The process crashed and the diagnostic output was produced by the OS (or shell).

Comment: @Leon, I suspected as much. Is there any way to capture this output? I would like to record it so I can file a bug report with the package developer.
Josh, yup the program definitely crashed. I could post my script but the error is being generated by a package I am using as far as I can tell so my code probably wouldn't show the source of the error so might not be useful here.

Comment: You can introduce a level of indirection and execute the command in a subshell. Then such diagnostic can be captured as `stderr` of the shell process executing that command. The catch is that such diagnostic is suppressed in non-interactive shells, so you must take special measures to tell the shell behave as interactive: `bash -i -c "python -u edge_prediction_stats.py" 2>&1 | tee ./screengrab.dat`

Comment: Note however that it looks like the crashing process was `tee` rather than `python` (in my experiments diagnostics of a crashed/aborted process executed in a pipe are printed only if the process is the last one in the pipe). In that case the previous advice would not help.

Comment: @Leon, I have just rerun the process without console redirection and thus without `tee`. It persists so isn't caused by `tee`. If you would like to propose your comment as an answer I shall test it and accept it if it works. I will update the initial post to show the complete error output in case it is of interest.

Comment: @P-M It turned out that this kind of diagnostics cannot be captured using the method that I proposed earlier. The correct solution is in the accepted answer to a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616061/glibc-backtrace-cant-redirect-output-to-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [glibc backtrace - can't redirect output to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616061/glibc-backtrace-cant-redirect-output-to-file)

Comment: If I understand the linked post correctly setting the environment variable `LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_` to `1` the currently uncaptured error message will be redirected to `stderr` and then captured? And that works even after the python process has died? Or does the error get generated before the process dies?

Comment: @P-M Simply setting the environment variable `LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_` to 1 will solve your problem (nothing else is required).