# How to suppress the error message: "Error in `./hubbard.exc': corrupted size vs. prev_size"?

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, error-suppression

I have a very old program (from the late 80s) written in C++ and I somehow managed to get it running on `Ubuntu 16.04 64Bit`. Even if it produces an error at the end, the results are okay. Since it seems to be impossible to compile that program nowadays (it makes use of a very old version of the proprietary library NAG) I cant fix the problem in the source code and have to live with the error. I need to run this program in a loop and the error message completely clutters my screen and prevents me from seeing relevant messages. I tried to suppress the message by using calls like `./hubbard.exc 2>/dev/null` and variants of it like `&>/dev/null`, but the error message is still printed to screen. So I conclude, that this error message is neither printed to `stdout` nor to `stderr`.

I would be grateful for any help to suppress this error message or for an advise on how to suppres all output of the shell!

In case that it would not be possible to suppress this error message in the shell it would also help me to find a way to run the program from a Python3 script (using `subprocess` or `os.system`) without that the error is printed to screen.

The error message Im talking about looks as follows:

```
*** Error in `./hubbard.exc': corrupted size vs. prev_size: 0x0a350a98 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x67377)[0xf7d5e377]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6d2f7)[0xf7d642f7]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6e48a)[0xf7d6548a]
./libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3(__builtin_vec_delete+0x24)[0xf7f5ea44]
./hubbard.exc[0x80b4ad4]
./hubbard.exc[0x808e141]
./hubbard.exc[0x805352d]
./hubbard.exc[0x805257f]
./hubbard.exc[0x80527c5]
./hubbard.exc(fwrite+0xc7)[0x8049623]
./hubbard.exc[0x80b7779]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0xfa87)[0xf7f89a87]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x2e993)[0xf7d25993]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-080bd000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 15208152                           /mnt/data/Downloads/Ausfuehrbar/hubbard.exc
080bd000-080cb000 rwxp 00074000 08:16 15208152                           /mnt/data/Downloads/Ausfuehrbar/hubbard.exc
080cb000-080cf000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
098ee000-0a51e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
f7b00000-f7b21000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f7b21000-f7c00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7cf6000-f7cf7000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f7cf7000-f7ea7000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 917535                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
f7ea7000-f7ea9000 r-xp 001af000 08:02 917535                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
f7ea9000-f7eaa000 rwxp 001b1000 08:02 917535                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
f7eaa000-f7ead000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f7ead000-f7f00000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 917512                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
f7f00000-f7f01000 r-xp 00052000 08:02 917512                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
f7f01000-f7f02000 rwxp 00053000 08:02 917512                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
f7f0d000-f7f29000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 917507                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
f7f29000-f7f2a000 rwxp 0001b000 08:02 917507                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
f7f2a000-f7f2b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f7f2b000-f7f61000 r-xp 00000000 08:16 15208227                           /mnt/data/Downloads/Ausfuehrbar/libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3
f7f61000-f7f72000 rwxp 00036000 08:16 15208227                           /mnt/data/Downloads/Ausfuehrbar/libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3
f7f72000-f7f75000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f7f75000-f7f78000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [vvar]
f7f78000-f7f7a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [vdso]
f7f7a000-f7f9d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 917518                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
f7f9d000-f7f9e000 r-xp 00022000 08:02 917518                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
f7f9e000-f7f9f000 rwxp 00023000 08:02 917518                             /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
ff8f5000-ff916000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack]
```

Comment: Yes the redirection works for example with `ls`. I tried to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` using `ls 1>ls.out` and `ls --foo 2>ls.err` and both worked. Also I suppressed the error from `ls` by `ls --foo 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: I think the error does not occur in the program directly but merely in a call to a function (or whatever) of the library `libc`. Therefore Geno's solution was very promising but sadly didnt work for me.

Comment: maybe `libm` has a similar flag as `libc`? Good luck.

Comment: @usr2564301, not that big an accomplishment -- writing to `/dev/tty` isn't exactly atypical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `export LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_=1` to let this backtrace go to stderr, then use `2>/dev/null` to drop that error message, which like

```
$ LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_=1 ./hubbard.exc 2>/dev/null
```

, see [glibc backtrace - can't redirect output to file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616061/9035237) for more detail.

Comment: Hello Geno. Thank you very much for your answer! I just tried it and sadly this seems not to work for me. In your link they also seem to talk about Fedora, but I dont know if that ist the reason why it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @TMueller83 The `export` wasn't supposed to be there. Could you try it again? If it doesn't work, please be more specific about how it fails (does it still show the message? does it do nothing? what?)

Comment: The linked answer and ML post indicate a trailing underscore, as in `LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_=1`. That underscore is not a typo.

Comment: I'd sorry for making some inconvenience by errors, thank you for correct my typo.

Comment: Hey Geno and Charles! Thank you both a lot for the correction! It works now with the underscore. Thank you very much again!!

Answer (score -1):

I'm no expert but I believe that this old software isn't adapting well to the 'new' Ubuntu. I believe you should either find a more resent program that has the same function as the error causing one or just find a new version of the program.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! Sadly there is no other program with the same functionality or a more recent version. Its a scientific code for solving a very specific problem, which was done in the late 80s. So this is really the only program that exists for this purpose.

Comment: I know this sounds like a long shot but try using it on a virtual machine of an old software. Like an older version of Windows.

Comment: Hi Ron, thank you for your answer! But I think this is also not possible, because I call this program from within my own code which is written in Python3 using a lot of packages like scipy, numpy and so on. So even if I can run the old program in a VM I probably cant use it in combination with my own code which is what I need.

Comment: This might sound weird, but if your computer behalves that this pop-up errors are pop-up 'adds', if you download any basic add blocker, it just might suppress the errors. I am running out of ideas. Sorry man, I tried my best.

Comment: Hey Ron, thank you again! This program runs in the terminal (bash) on Linux not in a web browser or something like that. I never heard of an add blocker for the terminal and a quick Google search also didnt gave me any related results.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, I have graven every Idea I had. I hope someone more knowledgeable helps you with your issue.